# How can I add a preview to my custom PowerPoint templates?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I create lots of PowerPoint presentation templates to speed-up my work on recurring activities and presentation needs. I saved my custom templates in my documents (Custom Office Templates folder) and made sure this path is the one by default for custom office templates in PowerPoint.
Consequently, whenever I go to **File > New** I can then click on **Custom** to display my own templates and I see them all!

However, they are all looking the same because my templates do not embed any **preview** of my presentation, and I'd love to have a visual so I immediately recognize which template is which.

I tried to search on Google but to no avail, I cannot put my hand on a tutorial explaining how to add a preview to a custom template in PowerPoint.

Does anyone here know how to do that? I would be so happy and grateful :).
Thank you.

Comment: May I know which version of PowerPoint you are using?

Comment: Sure, I'm on Windows 11, Office 365 and currently PowerPoint version 2306 (Build 16529.20226)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which platform (mac/windows/web) you're using or what version of Office you have, so any answers you get may not apply.

Here, I have Office 2021/Windows

If I go to File | Info and click the v next to Properties and choose Advanced Properties, on the Summary tab, I can put a check next to Save Preview Picture.

When I do that, the POTX file I save gets a preview ... whatever's on the first slide.

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution! I never paid attention to that little v on that button! I am on Windows +O365 Monthly Enterprise updates.

Comment: It's *very* well hidden nowadays.